# Delphi 7 GIF in picture Dialog

Tags: delphi, gif

I am using Delphi 7 and the OpenPictureDialog to open / preview various images. This works fine when opening a bmp, jpg, etc.; however, if I try to do the same with a gif I get the following error. Anyone got any idea why or have a fix for it?

thanks

Colin

[image]

Comment: Delphi 7 does not support GIF images. For more info go through this link http://delphi.about.com/od/graphics/a/delphigif.htm

Comment: @Bharat: Well, today Delphi does. But back in the Delphi 7 days, this was true.

Comment: @Andreas: You are correct i modified my comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this [TGIFImage](http://www.tolderlund.eu/delphi/gifimaged2010b.zip). This is the original unit which was donated to CodeGear in 2006. It supports Delphi7.

copy GifImage.pas to your project path (from gifimaged2010b.zip) ,
and add to your uses list ;

thats all

It will automatically add GIF in filters for openpicturedialog (****)

Comment: Is there anyway to use this so I can show an Gif in the openpicturedialog?

Comment: Don't forget to add GifImage to uses

Answer (score 4):

Just use the [GraphicEx library](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=13&Itemid=33) by Mike Lischke. Just add a couple files to your uses list and your application natively supports GIF, TIFF, PNG and many many others. The standard TImage will work with them and also the TPictureDialog (along with all others standard components that use TGraphic - take note that some features will only work at runtime).

Answer (score 2):

If you use our free syngdiplus unit, you'll get GIF, JPEG and TIFF image support at once, by using the gdiplus library, available on every Windows since Windows XP. It supports loading and saving pictures, and the preview in TPictureDialog. And your exe size with increase much less than with GraphicEx or TGifImage.

Works from Delphi 6 up to Delphi XE.

And you'll be able to draw any TCanvas with anti-aliaising.

See http://synopse.info/forum/viewforum.php?id=4

Answer (score 0):

Delphi 7 simply doesn't support GIF images. This has led to a number of [third-party components](http://delphi.about.com/od/graphics/a/delphigif.htm) for reading GIF files. However, as of Delphi 2006 (IIRC), the RTL/VCL *can* read GIF files as well. Just include `GifImg` in the uses clause. (In fact, as of Delphi 2009, the RTL/VCL can also read PNG files. And then there is really no need for GIF support, because the PNG file format is superior in almost every way. The only thing supported by GIF that is not supported by PNG is (low-quality<sup>(1)</sup>) animations.)

<sup>(1)</sup> GIF only supports 256 colours.